# Validate Cognito session in Lambda function

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have some data stored in DynamoDB. In order to retrieve the data, I'm requiring users to be authenticated against Cognito user pool. I have managed to authenticate users successfully using AWS-Amplify library and Cognito returns following JSON data after successful authentication :

```
{  
  "username":"....",
  "pool":{  
     "userPoolId":"....",
     "clientId":"...",
     "client":{  
        "endpoint":"....",
        "userAgent":"aws-amplify/0.1.x js"
     },
     "advancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag":true,
     "storage":{  
        "loglevel:webpack-dev-server":"INFO"
     }
  },
  "Session":"abcd12345", <-------------------------------------------
  "client":{  
     "endpoint":"......",
     "userAgent":"aws-amplify/0.1.x js"
  },
  "signInUserSession":null,
  "authenticationFlowType":"USER_SRP_AUTH",
  "storage":{  
     "loglevel:webpack-dev-server":"INFO"
  },
  "challengeName":"NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED",
  "challengeParam":{  
     "userAttributes":{  
        "email_verified":"true",
        "phone_number_verified":"true",
        "phone_number":"...",
        "email":"....."
     },
     "requiredAttributes":[  

     ]
  }
}
```

I have implemented Lambda function with API Gateway to handle data request from client. My question is, is there a way to validate the session value ( returns by Cognito ) inside Lambda function, so that I can ensure user is authenticated before I return data?

Answer (score 2):

May be you found a solution to this, then I hope it will help someone else.

If I got your question correctly you can use [AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html)

and do it this way:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const cisp = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     const accessToken = event.accessToken;
     const cispParams = {
         "AccessToken": accessToken
     };

     cisp.getUser(cispParams, (err, result) => {
         if (err) {
             console.log(err);
             callback(err);
         } else {
             // code in this part is reached only if accessToken is valid.
             // So add your code to respond to a verified user here.
         }
         // rest of your Lambda code.
```

But accessToken will not be there by default. You have to pass it from front end.

```
//your code to generate API Gateway url// 
+ '?accessToken=' + session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
```

Then setup API Gateway to pass it to Lambda (can search for how to pass url params to Lambda through API Gateway).