# AWS "CognitoUserSession" always returning true even if the tokens are expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a lambda function which contains the following code;

```
    import {
      CognitoRefreshToken,
      CognitoAccessToken,
      CognitoIdToken,
      CognitoUserSession
    } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
........................
..........................
          const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
          const RefreshToken = new CognitoRefreshToken({
            RefreshToken: body.refreshToken
          });
          const IdToken = new CognitoIdToken({
            IdToken: body.idToken
          });
          const AccessToken = new CognitoAccessToken({
            AccessToken: body.accessToken
          });
          const sessionData = {
            IdToken: IdToken,
            AccessToken: AccessToken,
            RefreshToken: RefreshToken
          };
          const cachedSession = new CognitoUserSession(sessionData);
          if(cachedSession.isValid()) {
            //session is valid
          } else {
            //session expired(idToken and accessToken has expired)
          }
```

The problem I am facing is the check **cachedSession.isValid()** is always returning true even if the **idToken** and **accessToken** has expired. 
But from their official documentation it should return true only when the **accessToken** and **idToken** is valid.

What is wrong here. Any help would be very much appreciated.

For reference I followed this https://gist.github.com/kndt84/5be8e86a15468ed1c8fc3699429003ad for implementing the authorization flow.

Comment: I found the answer here. Hope it helps someone too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010309/validate-cognito-session-in-lambda-function

Comment: I followed the same gist and have the same problem. The solution is to use CognitoIdentityServiceProvider instead of CognitoUserSession for session/token vlaidation ?